# dabezium mongo connector in local

Tags: debezium

I am trying to setup debezium in local and getting this error

< ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:96) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding. at java.base/java.util.Properties.loadConvert(Properties.java:663) at java.base/java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:457) at java.base/java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:409) at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadProps(Utils.java:687) at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadProps(Utils.java:673) at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.parseConnectorConfigurationFile(ConnectStandalone.java:152) at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.processExtraArgs(ConnectStandalone.java:82) at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli.startConnect(AbstractConnectCli.java:150) at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli.run(AbstractConnectCli.java:94) at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:182) [2024-03-19 00:54:02,199] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect`

Though there is no such special character in any properties file